# pointers, pointer tot pointer, exc

Tags: c++, pointers

We need to understand the next code for college. Everything goes fine till the this instruction :

```
(*((*q1)+2))++;
```

Can someone tell me what's the effect of that instruction? q1 or p1 doesn't change. Here is the whole exercise.

```
 double a = 2;
 double b[] = {1,3,5};
 double c[] = {4,6,8,10};
 double & d = a;
 double* p1 = b;
 double* p2 = &c[1];
 double **q1 = &p2;
 double **q2 = &p1;
 (*q1)++;
 a = **q1-*(p1+1);
 q1 = q2;
 (*((*q1)+2))++;
 p2-=2;
 **q1 = *p2;
 *q2 = &c[1];
 b[2] -= *(p2+3)-**q1;
 d = c[1];
 cout << a << endl << b[0] << endl << b[1] << endl << b[2] << endl;
```

Comment: `(*((*q1)+2))++` is `q1[0][2]++`.

Comment: Just evaluate it from inside the () outward, just as it would execute.

Comment: _@Steven_ Do you know http://cdecl.org/ already?

Answer (score 3):

Considering that `q1` is a `double**` :

```
    *q1         Dereference q1, obtaining a double*&
   (   )+2      Add 2, ending up pointing two double's further
 *(       )     Dereference where we are, obtaining a double&
(          )++; Increment that last double.
```

Answer (score 0):

Work from the inside out.

`(*((*q1)+2))++;`

`(*q1)` is `p2` so replace.

```
(*(p2 + 2))++;
```

`p2 + 2` is the address of `c[3]` so replace

```
(*(&c[3])++;
```

`*(&c[3])` is `10` so replace

```
10++ is 11
```

Answer (score 0):

`(*((*q1) + 2))++;` is equivalent to `(*(p1 + 2))++;`